# Use single GPIO out to reset multiple lines

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, reset

I want to use a single Raspberry Pi GPIO out  to reset  two lines: LCD and CTP. What would be a correct schematic ? Can I simply connect both lines together ?
Both devices are "no-name", i.e. no schematic available.
LCD IC is HX8379A, CTP is FT6236.

Comment: Add (a lot) more details., what LCD? What is a CTP? Part numbers at least,  and ideally links to datasheets are requisite inputs to answer your question.

Comment: @vicatcu I added some details, that's all I got. I would prefer a "safe" way to combine  reset lines as soon as  schematics aren't available.

Comment: Sharing is beside the point - without specs you can't even determine if it's appropriate to connect them to *individual* pins on a pi.

Comment: Of course you can connect to individual pins, here is nothing to discuss. This question is about sharing one GPIO pin to reset both ICs.

Comment: "here is nothing to discuss" - Try again. For a start, are the two reset lines active high or active low? Maybe one of each, and in that case there is nothing to discuss, alright. How do you know? Do they both use that same voltage levels? Perhaps one of them uses a voltage higher than the  Pi, and maybe connecting to the Pi would destroy the driver for that pin. Try not to dismiss useful questions because you don't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are both active low +3.3 Vmax.

From the datasheets I see no reason why you can’t simply connect them together, assuming you’re willing to sacrifice individual control.

Comment: ok, I was thinking the same, just wanted to get an approval

Answer (score 0):

I looked up datasheets via Google. Both resets appear to be active low.  3.3 volt signaling seems OK for high on both, thigh it's the max allowed for one of them, whose typical spec says 1.8V. So anyway,  you should be able to wire both to the same 3.3V GPIO pin on the Pi. Probably not a horrible idea to wire a 100 ohm resistor in series with the signal to each device,  but will probably work fine without it.